# Auto-fill formula that references numerical worksheet names

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autofill

I need to auto-fill this formula in a column in a spreadsheet:

```
=COUNTIFS('1'!$D$3:$D$101,FALSE,'1'!$I$3:$I$101,"Name")
```

**'1'** being a sheet name in both criteria range. I have up to 31 sheet names (representing each day of the month).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&ROW(1:1)&"'!D3:D101"), FALSE, INDIRECT("'"&ROW(1:1)&"'!I3:I101"), "Name")
```

Fill down as necessary. The **$** are no longer necessary since the cell range references are text and will not change.